# Display Images in TextView html

Tags: java, android, image

I state that I have already read all the other questions but none is right for me.My app retrieves data from a database. If I put in the database   in the app does not display the image, while the other tag html yes because i put:

```
Text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.article.text);
String formattedText = db.getText();
Text.setText(Html.fromHtml(formattedText));
```

For images I would like something that the download so that they are always available. I tried to put ImageGetter but with the loading time of an article in the app increased a lot and very often said that Android is not responding (ANR). I also need something that resizes images depending on the display. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) download the latest jar add it in your project 
and use it like following

```
AQuerymAQuery;

mAquery=new AQuery(context);

mAquery.id(ImageView).auth(handle).image(ImagePath,true,true,400,0,null,0,0.0f);
```

Comment: There are other solutions?

Comment: yes there are other solutions but this one is quickest and simpletest